# Filtering by bool and has_child with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query in elasticsearch that works just fine:

```
body =
  size: opts.size
  query:          
    fuzzy_like_this:
    fields: ['title', 'content']
      like_text: opts.search
      fuzziness: 1
  filter:
    has_child:
      type: 'sku'
      filter:
        bool:
          must:
            range:
              regular_price:
                gte: opts.min_price
                lte: opts.max_price
  highlight:
    pre_tags: ['<strong>']
    post_tags: ['</strong>']
    fields:
      title:
        force_source: true
        fragment_size: 150
        number_of_fragments: 1
```

This gets `products` whose title or content fuzzy match `opts.search` and that have `skus` with the specified price range.  It works.

I'd now like to additionally exclude any `products` that have the `hide_from_catalog` boolean set to `true`.  However making the small change doesn't work as I expect:

```
body =
  size: opts.size
  query:          
    fuzzy_like_this:
    fields: ['title', 'content']
      like_text: opts.search
      fuzziness: 1
  filter:
    ### Adding this causes an error ###
    bool:                        
      must_not:                  
        term:                    
          hide_from_catalog: true
    has_child:
      type: 'sku'
      filter:
        bool:
          must:
            range:
              regular_price:
                gte: opts.min_price
                lte: opts.max_price
  highlight:
    pre_tags: ['<strong>']
    post_tags: ['</strong>']
    fields:
      title:
        force_source: true
        fragment_size: 150
        number_of_fragments: 1
```

I've played around a little and can't seem to get it working.  The failure looks like so:

```
SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch],... 
ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT \"has_child\"]
```

Which I assume is because the filtering is formatted incorrectly.

What would be the right way to add this additional filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `has_child` filter into the `bool` filter within a `must` clause, like this:

```
body =
  size: opts.size
  query:          
    fuzzy_like_this:
    fields: ['title', 'content']
      like_text: opts.search
      fuzziness: 1
  filter:
    bool:                        
      must_not:                  
        term:                    
          hide_from_catalog: true
      must:                  
        has_child:
          type: 'sku'
          filter:
            bool:
              must:
                range:
                  regular_price:
                    gte: opts.min_price
                    lte: opts.max_price
  highlight:
    pre_tags: ['<strong>']
    post_tags: ['</strong>']
    fields:
      title:
        force_source: true
        fragment_size: 150
        number_of_fragments: 1
```